# The access token acquired won't update the scopes value

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, office365

I'm using this site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx to do Authorization Code Grant Flow with the goal of reading my office 365 calendars using this type of flow. The problem is that when I request for an oauth token the response is not updating the "scope" variable. I'm requesting the oauth token using this POST call "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token" and passing in the body my grant_type, redirect_uri, client_id, client_secret, code, resource. The response is 200OK but for scope it only reads -> "'scope': 'Contacts.Read'" when it should also have Calendars.Read as well. In manage.windowsazure.com for the app that has the same client_id I'm passing in has the read calendars checked as well as the read contacts checked. When I first got my authorization code by typing this into the browser "login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize" I only had "Contacts Read" checked. But now every time I type that into my browser it skips the page where I accept my app to look at my calendars and contacts page. When I login with someone else's computer and get the auth code and request the token it updates their scope to both contacts and calendar and works fine. For me I'm getting a new Auth code in the url but it skips the page where I could accept my app to look at my contacts AND calendars. I'm getting a new authorization each time. I tried clearing my browsing data but It still wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the user to logon again so they can consent to the new scope. Try adding `prompt=consent` to your logon URL.

This works much nicer in the [v2 app model](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview/), which does dynamic scopes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I appended to my string for oAuth2/Authrorize the "&prompt=login" text it asks me to login again like you said. After entering in my credentials it still redirects back with a code in the url and skips the page where I accept my app to look at my "Contacts.Read" and "Calendar.Read". Any other thoughts?

Comment: Oops, I may have misspoke. I believe it's `prompt=consent`. Let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yep that fixed it. Thank you very much!